# Sort a file based on a name and age, without displaying the name

Tags: bash, terminal

In bash I need to sort continent;Country;Capital, so for example, Europe;France;Paris.
I only need the European countries and in the new file, I need to display them without the word Europe.
I tried `cat ../world.capitals | sort -u > europe.capitals`  but this only sorts them on name, and does not remove the word europe and does not single out the european countries.
[source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlNkR.png)

Comment: Can you post an extract from the source file.

Comment: @RamanSailopal I posted it.

Comment: Can you paste it within the post and not through a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the lines beginning with "Europe" using `grep`, remove the first field using `cut`, and sort:

```
grep ^Europe world.capitals | cut -d ';' -f2- | sort > europe.capitals
```

You can combine the first two steps using `sed` in a single command:

```
sed -n 's/^Europe;//p' world.capitals | sort > europe.capitals
```